# Plot multicolor vertical lines by using ggplot to show average time taken for each type as facet. Each type will have different vertical lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a chart in R where it will show me vertical lines for each type in facet.

df is the dataframe with person X takes time in minutes to reach from A to B and so on.

I have tried below code but not able to get the result.

```
df<-data.frame(type =c("X","Y","Z"), "A_to_B"= c(20,56,57), "B_to_C"= c(10,35,50), "C_to_D"= c(53,20,58))

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1,y = df$type)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(type~.)
```

I have attached image from excel which is desired output but I need only vertical lines where there are joins instead of entire horizontal bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use facets in your case, because there are only 3 variables.

So, to get a similar plot in R using ggplot2, you first need to reformat the dataframe using gather() from the tidyverse package. Then it's in long or tidy format.

To my knowledge, there is no geom that does what you want in standard ggplot2, so some fiddling is necessary.

However, it's possible to produce the plot using geom_segment() and cumsum():

```r
library(tidyverse)

# First reformat and calculate cummulative sums by type. 
# This works because factor names begins with A,B,C 
# and are thus ordered correctly.

df <- df %>% 
  gather(-type, key = "route", value = "time") %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(cummulative_time = cumsum(time))

segment_length <- 0.2

df %>% 
  mutate(route = fct_rev(route)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color = route)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(type) + segment_length, xend = as.numeric(type) - segment_length, y = cummulative_time, yend = cummulative_time)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3"), labels=c("Z", "Y","X"))+
    coord_flip() +
    ylim(0,max(df$cummulative_time)) +
    labs(x = "type")
```

[image: Line plot]

### EDIT

This solutions works because it assigns values to X,Y,Z in scale_x_discrete. Be careful to assign the correct labels! Also compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674047/7648774).

Comment: Thank you @MMWeb for your answer. But I need only vertical lines and no horizontal bars in ggplot.

Comment: Do you mean thiner bars? You would set this with geom_col(width = 0.01). geom_line() is used if you have two continuous variables, which you don't have.

Comment: Hi @MMWeb, i have edited my question. request you to look into it. thanks.

Comment: Here you go. I hope this is what you are looking for.